# setting up contentful preview page using Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, preview, gatsby, contentful

I am building a blog page using gatsby and contentful.

I finished setting up the live website using delivery API, and now trying to set up the preview page. I want it to work so that when I click "Open Preview" button from the content, the exact draft I was working on pops up on a preview page. In that way, I can check how it will look like in live website.

right now in my gatsby-config, I have two different plugins, one for preview and one for delivery.

```
{
  resolve: `gatsby-source-contentful`,
  options: {
    spaceId: `space-id`,
    accessToken: `preview-access-token`,
    host: `preview.contentful.com`
  }
},
{
  resolve: 'gatsby-source-contentful',
  options: {
    spaceId: 'space-id',
    accessToken:
      'delivery-access-token'
  }
},
```

like this. But I'm not 100% sure what I should do after this. How do I make a preview page using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you're able to use the live Preview API with Gatsby without doing a full rebuild. You might have luck using a Netlify site integrated with your Contentful event hooks.

In any case, configuring multiple instances of `gatsby-source-contentful` is unlikely to go well. You probably want to use ENV to provide the API and host, then configure Netlify (or wherever you're building) to use the appropriate token and host for the desired result.

Comment: @YegeonSeo You should accept the answer using the little outline of a checkmark to the left. This will award reputation points and helps others know that 1) this question has been answered and 2) this answer resolved the issue.

Comment: Just did! Thanks :)

Comment: Is this hold true today still with Gatsby Cloud? I believe this a big draw back of Gatsby that you cannot preview the content without doing a rebuild. What is the point of the preview URL then I don't really understand? I reached out to Contentful CMS and they reassured me it is possible, while others say it is not possible so I am very confused.

Comment: @Aquasar It depends on the integration. I don't think the Contentful source plugin has a way of streaming changes, but [gatsby-source-sanity](https://github.com/sanity-io/gatsby-source-sanity) will do this (within seconds of making a change in the CMS it updates on Gatsby Preview or in your development environment).

Comment: @coreyward wow that is crazy, I am not sure how that even works but that is good to know. Do you know if Butter CMS has this functionality and how can I know whether a CMS has this or not. Seems like most of the support people are not very technical

Comment: @Aquasar I would look up the source plugin for the CMS you're considering and see if they make any mention of changes, previewing, live reloading, or streaming.